# How do i specify the executable file's name with csc?

Tags: c#, csc

Is there a csc command line compiler equivalent to g++'s -o switch? Obviously, I have added it to path.

Comment: `csc /?` from the command line shows the switches and options it offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply [`-out:filename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/out-compiler-option) for the C# compiler.